# Can't access Datasnapshot value with Cloud Functions

Tags: javascript, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, google-cloud-functions

I'm trying to use cloud functions to check periodically if a meeting deadline has passed. But I can't figure out how to access the value of the snapshot that I get returned. Here is my code:

```
const functions = require('firebase-functions');
const admin = require('firebase-admin');
admin.initializeApp(functions.config().firebase);


exports.checkForMeetings = functions.https.onRequest((req, res) => 
{
    var query = admin.database().ref("meetings").orderByChild("deadline");
    query.once("value").then((snapshot) => 
    {
        var currentDate = new Date();
        var currentTime = currentDate.getTime();
        var seconds = (currentTime / 1000).toFixed(0);
        var deletion = {};
        var updates = {};

        console.log(seconds);

        snapshot.forEach((child) =>
        {
            console.log(child.value)
            if (seconds > child.value)
            {
                //Rest of the code here
            }
        }
    }
}
```

The meeting database node looks like this

[image: database example]

Right now the console just prints 'undefined' when I try to print the deadline value, and the if statement doesn't execute.
What's the solution to this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The [`Query#once()`](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/admin/node/admin.database.Query#once) method callback returns a [`DataSnapshot`](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/admin/node/admin.database.DataSnapshot), likewise so does the [`DataSnapshot#forEach()`](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/admin/node/admin.database.DataSnapshot#forEach) iterator, so you'll need to use the [`val()`](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/admin/node/admin.database.DataSnapshot#val) method to obtain the value:

> ### val
>
> `val()` returns any type
>
> Extracts a JavaScript value from a `DataSnapshot`.
>
> **Returns**
>
> `any type` The DataSnapshot's contents as a JavaScript value (Object, Array, string, number, boolean, or `null`).

For example:

```
snapshot.forEach((child) =>
{
    console.log(child.val())
    if (seconds > child.val())
    {
        //Rest of the code here
    }
}
```

Comment: Okay, it now prints the following to the console:
{ deadline: 1509610227, name: 'Test Meeting', users: { '8YUDtUJuIde8fLaHCfeuSNsHUyq2', etc }

How do I access the deadline value from this?

Comment: You can use [`DataSnapshot#child()`](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/admin/node/admin.database.DataSnapshot#child) to access child values, so: `child.child("deadline").val()`.

Comment: Grimthorr I have another question for you, is there anywhere I can contact you?

Comment: Sure, you can create another question, or [continue this discussion in Stack Overflow chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/158084/).